# Solve the inequality $\frac{\log_ax}{x^2+(a-4)x+4-2a}\le0$

Tags: inequality

Solve the inequality

$$\frac{\log_ax}{x^2+(a-4)x+4-2a}\le0$$

#### My work:

If $1>a>0$ then $x \in (0;1] \cup (2; + \infty)$ .

If $3>a>1$ then $x \in (0;2) $ .

If $3 \le a<4$ then $x \in (a-2;2) \cup (0; 1]$ .

If $a=4$ then $x \in (0;1]$ .

If $a>4$ then $x \in (0;1] \cup (2; a-2)$ .

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly from $\log_ax$ you have $a \ne 1$.

Then the inequality is equivalent to:
$$\log x \cdot \log a \cdot (x-2) \cdot(x+a-2) \le 0$$ and $$(x-2)(x+a-2) \ne 0$$

Then you could discuss on $a$'s value and write up the solution.